# Operations on regular languages

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am taking a course on natural language processing that assumes the students have some background on theory of computation. I dont, but have read up till chapter 3 of the book "Speech and Language Processing by Jufrasky".

I therefore understand the following

- regular expressions and regular languages
- operations on regular languages (union, cross product)
- finite state automatas and the construction of FSA's given a regular expression

Unfortunately, I couldn't solve a single question below and am not even sure if my understanding of the question is correct. The red ticks are the solutions. I hope the people here can help out an NLP newbie.

Definitions for the notations are as follows:

$+$ which means ‘one or more of the previous character’. (book definition)

$\bigotimes$ cross product

So this is my most likely wrong understanding of the first statement: 
$L_1+ \bigotimes L_2 + $

If I have

$L_1 = \{aa,ab,aab\}$

$L_2 = \{b,ab,abb\}$

then $L_1 + $ requires me to have at least one occurrence of $L_1$. And so $L_1+ \bigotimes L_2 + $ would result in a set that could have at least one of the element from $L_1$ concatenated with at least one from $L_2$ ? So I could get something like $aa \ aa \ b$ ? Where the two $aa$ comes from $L_1$.

Would this be correct ?

[image]

Comment: Egads, that book uses horrible notation. Normally, we write $L^+$ for what Jufrasky calls "$L+$", since $+$ looks like a binary operator and often means union in the context of formal languages. Could you clarify exactly what $\otimes$ does? That's not notation I've ever seen before and the only thing I can guess is that $L_1\otimes L_2 = \{w_1w_2\mid w_1\in L_1,\ w_2\in L_2\}$, but I assume that's what $\circ$ means.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the question states that $\bigotimes$ denote the transducers cross product. Based on my understanding it would mean that if I have $L_1=\{a,b\}$ and $L_2=\{c,d\}$ then their cross product is $L=\{ac,ad,bc,bd\}$.

Comment: I've never heard of a "transducers cross product" but the definition you give is the same as the one I guessed. That's normally just referred to as concatenation (though it is essentialyl a form of Cartesian product, so using $\otimes$ as notation for that is unusual but not crazy). So what does $\circ$ mean?

Comment: Would a "finite state automata cross product" make more sense ? I heard my lecturer mention it in class that they are the same. And from the videos I have watched it would seem that the cross product and composition are done on FSA's. This was the video  I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EaFxgel8eg&t=705s

According to the book by Jufrasky, composition is the concatenation of 2 FSAs i.e. the output of FSA 1 is feed to the input of FSA 2.

Comment: Sorry, there's a lot of back-and-forth here and I'm losing track. Could you please just add a clear definition of $\otimes$ and $\circ$ to your question. Jufrasky is using nonstandard notation and nonstandard terminology.

Comment: Is it possible that these exercises are about rational relations and finite state transducers instead of regular languages?
In this case $L_1 \otimes L_2 = \{(aa, b), (ab, b), (aab, b), (aa, ab), (ab, ab), (aab, ab), (aa, abb), (ab, abb), (aab, abb)\}$ with $L_1, L_2$ from the languages in the question. Consequently, the composition would be defined like $(u, u') \circ (v, v') = (uv, u'v')$.

Comment: I'm confused.  I can't tell what your question is.  Can you pick a single conceptual question you are not sure about and ask about that?  Are you asking us to explain what the notation means?  Are you asking us to check whether your solution is correct?  Are you asking us to solve one of these exercises?  Can you narrow the question down to focus on just one thing?  If you can't solve the exercise, that usually means there is some concept you don't understand.  Can you identify what that concept is, and ask just about the concept?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89191/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2685601/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/40354/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. Id like the community to solve one of the 4 parts of the question and give an example on it. Because I don't even know how to start. The 1st part has 3 options with only the first being ticked. Why is that correct and why are the other two wrong. With a simple example...

Comment: @PHPNick Aren't finite state transducers the same as regular languages, with regular languages just being the set of all strings that can be accepted by the finite state transducer ? Would you be so kind as to solve the first part of the question with a simple example ? i.e. the first 3 options.. why the answer is the first and not the other 2.

Comment: If you don't even know how to start, often that means there's some concept you don't understand or aren't quite clear on.  If you can figure out what that is, asking about that concept tends to lead to a better question -- one that is more focused, and that is more likely to be useful to others in the future.

Comment: No, finite state transducers are not the same as regular languages.  Explaining why would take more than a comment, but if your read the definitions of a finite-state transducer and a regular language you might start to get some hints.  Finite-state transducers don't accept strings; they transduce them (convert them to another string).